# SQL Server Queries - Baseline and Benchmarking

Tags: sql, sql-server

To baseline your SQL Server - we can run PERFMON, DMVs, Profiler to benchmarked/baseline.

But can anyone advise - how to capture QUERIES performance and see whether they r improving or degrading

So what im trying to do is - capture critical queries - and then monitor their execution duration on daily basis to see if any improvement on SERVER is helping or not

Hope I'm able to explain what I need help on.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is setup SQL traces and import the data into a table. This will allow you to monitor all queries being run and give useful information like:
- Query text
- Start and end times
- and 60-70 other data points

It is a bit detailed and I don't want to write a novel in here, but you can visit this link to get you started:

[SQL Trace](http://www.sqloptimizationsschool.com/Pages/Tracking%20Performance/Performance%20Tracing.aspx)

It gives you the introduction to tracing and also explains how to import the data from your trace file into the database (at the end). There are also links on the article to Microsoft's website that are important to review as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the trace files using [ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/).  It will show you the history of each query by day as you load the traces.  And full disclaimer: that's a tool I wrote and offer for free.

Comment: Per the FAQ, you need to dislcose that this is your product:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion.